# Некорректно работает Google Play Service

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-console, leaderboard

Есть игра под андроид, настроена таблица лидеров через Google Play Services, у меня работает все отлично, рекорд по очкам показывает, так же показывает мне других пользователей. Но некоторые пользователи когда нажимают на кнопку таблицы лидеров, она (таблица) открывается и тут же закрывается. В чем может быть косяк? В каком направлении искать, ни в консоле ни в игре ошибок нет. Не знаю можно ли сюда дать ссылку на игру для теста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что проблема в аккаунтах некоторых пользователей, для корректной работы нужно включить все пункты приложении Play игры[image: введите сюда описание изображения] представленные на изображении.